# iOS swift tableView header with JSON array

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a `UITableView`like this:

[image]

and a `tableView` data fetch from JSON with `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJson`:

JSON Data:

```
{
"timeline": {
"Milan": {
  "place": [
    {
      "name": "Place 1",
      "kind": "historic",
    },
    {
      "name": "Place 2",
      "kind": "historic",
    },
    {
      "name": "Place 3",
      "kind": "historic",
    },
    {
      "name": "Place 4",
      "kind": "historic",
    }
  ]
},
"Paris": {
  "place": [
    {
      "name": "Place 1",
      "kind": "historic",
    },
    {
      "name": "Place 2",
      "kind": "historic",
    },
    {
      "name": "Place 3",
      "kind": "historic",
    }
  ]
 }
}
}
```

my question is how I separate city place in one array that inherit from class called Place and put data in tableView like above image.

```
struct Place {
    var name = ""
    var type = ""
}
```

I wrote some code in `Alamofire` `.success`  but this is not enough:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value {
           let json = JSON(jsonData)
           if let items = json["timeline"].dictionary {

           for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in items {
               self.cityName.append(key)

                ...
           }

       }
   }
```

Comment: why you use for loop you just need data in one array and just fill it into table

Comment: https://grokswift.com/rest-with-alamofire-swiftyjson/ refer this link

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/75fa44dc0e3f2752973a79984b182d70

Check this link and if any problem then tell me. i give you basic idea of how to create tableview with header and selection.

**Happy coding**

Comment: ya send it in that chat

Comment: Lots of error in your code man what i do in that around 82 errors its show me

Comment: i send new version,I will thankful if you check this version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126952/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-mohammadreza).

Comment: @MohammadReza brother your problem solve then approve my answer so i can suggest my this answer to other user. thank you